# Close File Dialog Application

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code. This code opens the file browser.
But if you click Cancel or Close appears an error.
For this reason I try to put:

```
 If Not IsEmpty(diaFolder.SelectedItems) Then
```

But this doesn't work. What should I do?

```
Private Sub Image1_Click()
Dim diaFolder As FileDialog
' Open the file dialog
Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
diaFolder.Show

If Not IsEmpty(diaFolder.SelectedItems) Then
    Cells(1, 1) = diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)
    TextBox1 = diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)
End If

Set diaFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Since it generates a dynamic array I would advise you to use the [IsArrayEmpty function](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead:

`If diaFolder.SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then`